# How to hide / display a JPanel over time (JAVA, GRAPHICS, ANIMATION)

Tags: java, animation, graphics, synchronization

I need to show the panel 'basPanel' when the white circle stops for 15 sec. (Thread.sleep(15000)); hide it then, and show again at the next stop of the white circle.

My idea is to use .add(basPanel) / .remove(basPanel), but I can't figure out where to put the .add(basPanel) / .remove(basPanel).
I tried in the actionPerformed by it's a closed part, does not sync with the rest it sems.
How to sync this?

```
public class Robot0 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JPanel basPanel;

public Robot0(String nom, int larg, int haut){
    setTitle(nom); 
    setSize(larg, haut); 
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true); 

    JPanel basPanel = new JPanel();
    basPanel.setVisible(true);
    basPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    basPanel.setBounds(000, 250,larg-0,haut-250);
    this.add(basPanel);
}    


Timer tm = new Timer(1,this);    

private int posX = 0; 
private int posY = 0;
private int velX = 1; 


public int getPosX() {
return posX;
}    
public void setPosX(int posX) {
this.posX = posX;
}
public int getPosY() {
return posY;
}
public void setPosY(int posY) {
this.posY = posY;
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            //Draw the pathway 
            int xt[] = {50, 50, 250, 250, 350, 350};
            int yt[] = {50, 150, 150, 50, 50, 150};        
            g.drawPolyline(xt, yt, 6);  

            //On the pathway, draw 3 squares (the 3 rooms) 
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);    
            g.drawRect(35, 135, 30,30);
            g.drawRect(235, 35, 30,30);
            g.drawRect(335, 135, 30,30);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(40+posX,40+posY,20,20);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(45+posX,50+posY,55+posX,50+posY);
            g.drawLine(50+posX,45+posY,50+posX,55+posY);

            tm.start();
    }


int segment = 0;


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    //move along the 1st segment
    if (posY<100 && segment==0) {
    setPosY(posY + velX);
    }

    if(posY==100 && posX==0){
        segment = 1;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000); /

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Robot0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    //move along the second segment
    if (posX<=200 && segment==1) {
    setPosX(posX + velX);
    }

    if(posX==200 && posY==100){
        segment = 2;    
    }

    //move along the third segment
    if (posY>0 && segment==2) {
    setPosY(posY - velX);
    }

    if(posX==200 && posY==0){
        segment = 3;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Robot0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    //move along the fourth segment
    if (posX<300 && segment==3) {
    setPosX(posX + velX);
    }

    if(posX==300 && posY==0){
        segment = 4;
    }

    //move along the fifth segment
    if (posY<100 && segment==4) {
    setPosY(posY + velX);
    }

    if(posX==300 && posY==100){
        segment = 6;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Robot0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    repaint();
}



// Build the Panel
public static void main(String[] args){
Robot0 r = new Robot0("Robot0", 800, 600);    
}


}
```

Comment: 1) Instead of removing/adding panels you can use a `CardLayout`. The `CardLayout` allows multiple panels to share the same space on a frame, but only one can be visible at a time. 2) A Timer should NOT be started in a painting method. Your application should have a button or some other event to start/stop the animation. 3) Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame.

Comment: See the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) there are sections on: 1) `How to Use Card Layout` and 2) `Performing Custom Painting` for more information and examples.

Comment: I see. Will try this. Many thanks

Comment: The CardLaytout does not seems to meet my requirements: it seems it helps to switch between panels. I'd like 2 panels on one frame: one panel in the top, one in the bottom. And the one in the bottom shall sometimes be visible (active), sometimes hidden. Hence the .add / .remove idea

Comment: So the main panel is a BorderLayout. (See the tutorial). You add a panel to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START. Then you add a second Panel to the BorderLayout.CENTER. This panel will use a CardLayout. Then you add two child panels. One panel will contain your components, the other panel will be empty. You then just swap the panels as required.